# Testing view's arguments to controller actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have code like this in one of my views:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveWidget", "WidgetSet", 
          new { 
              widgetSetToWidgetMapId = item.MapRepositoryId, 
              containingWidgetSetRepositoryId = item.ContainingWidgetSetRepositoryId}, 
              null)
```

with code like this in my controller:

```
// GET: /WidgetSet/RemoveWidget/1
public ActionResult RemoveWidget(int widgetSetToWidgetMapId, string 
                                 containingWidgetSetRepositoryId)
```

We have unit tests around controller actions (mocking out DAL dependencies) and we also have end-to-end integration tests from the controller action all the way through our web services to the database and back.

But we have been bitten numerous times when someone refactors a controller action's parameter (eg. ) but does not update the view.

What options do i have to add automated testing to catch that. Ideally some simple unit test would added.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you've unit tests for RemoveWidget, doesn't it fail if user changes the param's since unit test cover both existence as well as functionality.

Comment: No it doesn't fail.  Since the unit test must know the parameters it will get refactored automaticly when a refactor happens on the controller method signature.  Perhaps this is a place where i can do route testing...  I haven't done much of it yet..

Comment: Perhaps you're right. It might needs to be covered in automated testing or any UI testing.